# Can displacement current cause heat?

Tags: electromagnetism

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current

Pretty self explanatory, if you have high voltage & high frequency can you produce enough current to release heat? Or is it just a mathematical fix for Maxwell equations?

Answer (score 0):

a familiar example is the microwave oven, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven

Comment: That's electromagnetic waves. I'm strictly speaking about electrical fields displacing ions\cations in a localized area with displacement current